# JQuery Toggle()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was watching a tutorial for using the JQuery toggle, and I want to use it on my site, But the thing is I want to div to be hidden initially on page load so, When somebody visit the page It is only a button saying some text to show the content, and when that button is clicked, then toggle and show the content, But as I am new I don't know how to stop its default opened state:

```
function random_script(element,speed){
$(element).toggle(speed);
}

<input type="button" value"Show Results?" onClick="random_script('#somediv',1000);"/>
<div id="somediv"></div>
```

So is there any solution for this?

Comment: The error was not germane to the question or the ultimate answer, but rather a red-herring. I agree that the edit war was silly (even though IMO @Christoph was right for making the code *correct*). If the OP's issue was the improperly-formed function, then I'd agree he was out of line, but it wasn't so he wasn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="random_script('#somediv',1000);">Show Results?</a>
<div id="somediv" style="display:none;"></div>
```

Alternative with JQuery ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NyDXk/)):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ​$('.showResult')​.click(function (){
        $(this).next('.result').toggle();
    });​​​​​​
</script>
<style>
    ​.result {
        display: none;
    }​
</style>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="showResult">Show Results?</a>
<div class="result">Some Result​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: @Waleed add speed to toggle as toggle(speed)

Comment: thanks for that and 1 more thing, I am refreshing a div using JQuery but, When I apply the script and save then view it. It gives me duplicate of that page some where on that page

Comment: @Waleed Make sure you clear the div <div_Name_Here>.empty() before you refresh it. JQuery just appends on to it.

Comment: @Waleed My mistake it's `$(<div_name_here).empty();`

Answer (score 2):

Add a css rule

```
#somediv{ display:none;}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to reverse the initial function of `toggle()` you have to hide the target element in the first place. You can achieve this by declaring `#somediv{display:none}` on it.

When doing this, `toggle()` will show the element.

Here you have an example **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QhBKy/)**.

Also you should not work with inline event-attribute but use real eventhandlers.

```
$("input").on("click".function(){
   random_script("#somediv",1000);
});

function random_script(element,speed){
    $(element).toggle(speed);
}
```

is the correct way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the `{}` for function.

```
function random_script(element,speed) {
  $(element).toggle(speed);
}
```

Comment: @Christoph why on earth do you alter his question? You modified his code.

Comment: @Christoph The codes are within the script tags, I don't think it's just a typo, surely he have copied/pasted the markup/script.

Comment: @Mihai he states an completely unrelated problem. His toggle works, so it can't be this simple syntax error. He just wants another initial state.