# Change css with jQuery in function

Tags: jquery, css

So, I have a following div's and function:

```
<div class="show" style="display:none;"> Show only when </div>
```

Then, jQuery function:

```
beforeSend : function(){
        jQuery('.show').html('?????');
    },
```

How do I make the jQuery function so that it changes the css of `class="show"` from "display:none" to visible?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery Toggle()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12033712/jquery-toggle)

Comment: yeah, could be. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this http://api.jquery.com/show/:

```
$('.show').show();
```

Comment: Also note that you can add additional parameters such as duration etc.

Comment: i see. Thank you! =) I will read on the link you added. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

As Kostas (+1) showed the simplest and most used one to show elements with the use of jquery `.show()` -  *you can hide element with `.hide()` and toggle their display with `.toggle()`*  -, to set CSS values with jQuery you can use this function `.css()`like this:

```
$(selector).css({'property1':numValue1, 'property2': 'stringValue2'});
```

for example: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tfthjz9b/)

```js
$('#change').on('click', function () {
    $('.something').css({'color': 'orange','background-color': 'maroon'});
});
```

```css
.something {
    color:white;
    font-size:1.5em;
    background-color:orange;
    padding:2px 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="something">Here is an example</p>
<button id="change">Change CSS</button>
```

Reference: **https://api.jquery.com/css/**

Comment: Thank you for the awesome example and explanation! =) Learned something new!